# React Native on ESP32 Webserver using SPIFFS

Tags: android, react-native, arduino, esp32

I want to create a mobile based dashboard utilizing temperature sensor in ESP32. ESP32 will act as webserver and websocket will be used to display the data as it is real time. I want the front end to display data in react-native as I want it to be mobile based. I want to ask whether I can put the react-native app in SPIFFS of ESP32 and utilize it there. I can find some links which show how to use react with ESP32 but not find information regarding react native on ESP32 webserver. So how can we use react-native to display data using ESP32 webserver.

What steps should I follow to display data using websockets through react-native in ESP32 without using wifi. I want to deploy the react-native app in SPIFFS of ESP32.

Comment: does it fit? what is the size of the application with all dependencies?

Comment: "Without using wifi"? How do you propose that the dashboard communicate with the ESP32?

Comment: @romkey I am using SoftAP configuration of ESP32 which makes this microcontroller a wifihotspot

Comment: @Juraj the total size is around 1MB. But how should I add it? In react.js we have index.html page but there is no such thing on react native. So how should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to WebSockets, you can do everything in React Native what you can in the web with React.js.

Comment: can you provide an example with react-native with esp32?

Comment: I have never used esp32, but I have worked with several implementations of WS.
If you have seen it done in React.js and have a code example as you mentioned, you can use that code as an example because when it comes to WS js runtime in React Native works the same way as it works in Web.